# Datatables header shifted

Tags: jquery, header, datatables

Hi i've got a problem with datatables (jquery) i cannot solve my own. can anybody help me or give me a hint`?

the problem is that the header of my datatables is shifted and not formatted well as you can see in the pic below.

![enter image description here][1]

but when i click on one entry in order to sort it it changes formatting and everything works fine.

![enter image description here][2]

i have included the datatable in a jquery ui dialog using jquery ui tabs. my code looks like this.

```
    <script>
$(function() {
    $("#rt").treeview();
    $("button").button({ 
        icons: {primary: "ui-icon-person"}}).click(function() {
            var id = this.id;window.location="rightsmanagement?nutzerrechte_vergeben&show=3&refine=";
            });
    }); 
    $.fn.tabbedDialog = function () {
        this.tabs();
        var wWidth = $(window).width();
        var dWidth = wWidth * 0.8;
        var dialogOptions = {
        modal: true,width: dWidth,minHeight: 520};
        this.dialog(dialogOptions);
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').append($('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'));
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').css({'position':'absolute','right':'0', 'top':'13px'});
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close > a').css({'float':'none','padding':'0'});
        var tabul = this.find('ul:first');
        this.parent().addClass('ui-tabs').prepend(tabul).draggable('option','handle',tabul);
        this.siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
        tabul.addClass('ui-dialog-titlebar');
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#controllerTab').tabbedDialog();
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#singleusertable').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": "280px",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "oLanguage": {"sUrl": "style/table/sprache.txt"},
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Benutzername", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Vorname", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Nachname", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Personalnummer", "aTargets": [ 4 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Abteilung", "aTargets": [ 5 ] },
            { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 6 ] },
            { "sWidth": "25%", "aTargets": [ 1] },
            ],"aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']]
    });
});



</script>
```

thx in advance for tips..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a trigger when you click on the tab click. In your case it would be something like this:

First of all add the datatables to a variable:

```
var oTable = $('#singleusertable').dataTable({
    ..

});
```

and then just reload after you are clicking at the second tab. Like this:

```
$("a[href=#tabs-2]").click(function()
{
    oTable.fnReloadAjax();
});
```

Your final script will look like this:

```
<script>
var oTable  = null;
$(function() {
    $("#rt").treeview();
    $("button").button({ 
        icons: {primary: "ui-icon-person"}}).click(function() {
            var id = this.id;window.location="rightsmanagement?nutzerrechte_vergeben&show=3&refine=";
            });
    }); 
    $.fn.tabbedDialog = function () {
        this.tabs();
        var wWidth = $(window).width();
        var dWidth = wWidth * 0.8;
        var dialogOptions = {
        modal: true,width: dWidth,minHeight: 520};
        this.dialog(dialogOptions);
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').append($('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'));
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').css({'position':'absolute','right':'0', 'top':'13px'});
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close > a').css({'float':'none','padding':'0'});
        var tabul = this.find('ul:first');
        this.parent().addClass('ui-tabs').prepend(tabul).draggable('option','handle',tabul);
        this.siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
        tabul.addClass('ui-dialog-titlebar');
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#controllerTab').tabbedDialog();

    $("#controllerTab a[href=#tabs-2]").click(function()
    {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });     
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#singleusertable').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": "280px",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "oLanguage": {"sUrl": "style/table/sprache.txt"},
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Benutzername", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Vorname", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Nachname", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Personalnummer", "aTargets": [ 4 ] },
            { "sTitle": "Abteilung", "aTargets": [ 5 ] },
            { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 6 ] },
            { "sWidth": "25%", "aTargets": [ 1] },
            ],"aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']]
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi johnny thx so far for your help. unfortunately it doesent work.. any idea why? my datatable isnt filled with ajax . it only renders a simple html table ...

Comment: Awesome your code snippet gave me the input i needed.  i tried it now with oTable.fnDraw() in the click event and it worked.  Thx to you. Can anybody tell me why it is neccessary to redraw it when i click on a tab?

Comment: I have updated my answer too. 
Actually the problem is that datatables try to calculate the width of the columns and if it is hidden (before you open the tab is hidden) it is difficult to calculate the width that's why it happens. It happens only when the table is hidden at the first side. Also consider that at datatables the header is a different html table than the body table.